# The value of the variable don't show in the other class

Tags: java, android, variables

I make a program in Eclipse to Android and I have a problem. I have this class where I show the artists. Inside the onClick method I want to send the "value" of the clicked listitem.

```
...public class ArtistActivity extends ListActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.listview);

    String[] artists = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.artists_array);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, artists));

    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
            {                   
                StringActivity sA = new StringActivity();
                sA.setArtist(((TextView) v).getText().toString());
                String asd = sA.getArtist();
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), asd/*((TextView) v).getText()*/, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent i = new Intent().setClass(getApplicationContext(), AlbumActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
    });
}}
```

Inside onClick when I do it with Toast then it shows the picked item, but in the other class don't. Here are the code where I store the value:

```
public class StringActivity {
private String artist="";

public String getArtist() {
    return(artist);
}

public void setArtist(String artist) {
    this.artist=artist;
}

public String toString() {
    return(getArtist());
}}
```

And here is the other class where it should show the value:

```
public class AlbumActivity extends Activity {
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    StringActivity sA = new StringActivity();

    String asd = sA.getArtist();
    TextView textview = new TextView(this);
    textview.setText("Hello " + asd + " World!");
    setContentView(textview);
}}
```

The hello world is there just because to see that there is nothing wrong with the textview. Maybe the problem is that it don't refresh (it's stay the same from the launch of the program - because when I give a value for the artist string in the StringActivity class then it shows, but when I click on an item it stay the same) or there is another problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `StringActivity` you create in your `onClick` listener is only visible inside the listener, not in your second activity! You have to use `Intent.putExtra()` to push some extras into the Intent, then use `Intent.getExtras()` in your second activity to get them back.

So change the onClick to:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
{                   
   String artist = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
   Intent i = new Intent().setClass(ArtistActivity.this, AlbumActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("artist", artist);
   startActivity(i);
}
```

And in the second activity's onCreate you can do:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

   String asd = extras.getString("artist");
   TextView textview = new TextView(this);
   textview.setText("Hello " + asd + " World!");
   setContentView(textview);
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you very much for your help! and mgronber for yours too!

Answer (score 4):

You are creating a new instance of `StringActivity` and then getting the value with `getArtist()`. It returns empty string because the instance is local and it has not been set to be anything else.

Unfortunately I have not done any Android development so I do not know how you should pass data around. Maybe it can be done with `Bundle` that is passed as parameter or maybe there is some other way. I guess it should be pretty easy to find if you search Android documentation and examples.

Comment: Yes you are right, but you could have elaborated how to do it ;)

Comment: I understand you answer but not really know what should I change. Can you please write it? Thank you!